# I cant install django-jquery : No matching distribution found for django-staticfiles-jquery

Tags: python, jquery, django, installation, pip

I have this version of python : Python 3.10.7

and this version for django : 3.2.15

I want to install jquery using :

```
pip install django-staticfiles-jquery
```

but i got this :

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-staticfiles-jquery (from versions: none)
```

```
ERROR: No matching distribution found for django-staticfiles-jquery
```

I dont know what's the problem

Comment: Well, I installed `django-jquery`, `django-staticfiles` and `django-staticfiles-jquery`, with Python 3.10. If there was a traceback we need to see it in full. If not — please run `pip install -vvv django-staticfiles-jquery`, [edit] the question and show us the entire text output.

Answer (score 1):

Try install  `django-jquery` :

```bash
pip install django-jquery
```

Comment: What is wrong with [django-staticfiles-jquery](https://pypi.org/project/django-staticfiles-jquery/)?

Comment: I do not Know , but I think Django-jquery it's work